# Mustache js - template for navigation not loaded sometimes

Tags: javascript, json, rendering, loading, mustache

I'm building a site with the help of Mustache js. There is quite a lot of data in the top navigation.

The problem is that approximately half of the time when I load the html, the navigation is not loaded/missing -The output is an empty div :

```
<div id="nav"> </div>
```

Here is the html code :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/lib/mustache.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/templates.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/main.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" type="text/css" media="all" />
</head>
<body id="productPage">
<div id="header">
    {{{header}}}
    <div id="nav">
        {{{nav}}}
    </div>
</div>
...
...
...
```

Here are the templates :

```
var Templates = {
    'header':           '<div id="headerWrapper">' +
                        '<div id="logo" class="left"><img src="images/logo.png"    /></div>'+
                        '<div class="right">'+
                            '<div class="search"></div>'+
                            '<div class="login">Login</div>'+
                        '</div>' +
                        '<ul class="user_type">'+
                            '{{#user_type_list}}'+
                            '<li><a href="{{user_type_element_link}}">{{user_type_element_text}}</a></li>'+
                            '{{/user_type_list}}'+
                        '</ul>'+
                        '<div id="menuWrapper" class="clearfix"></div>' +
                            '<div class="clearfix"></div> ' +
                        '</div>',
'nav':              '<ul id="menu">' +
                        '{{#menu_links}}' +
                        '<li class="menu_top" id="{{menu_id}}">' +
                            '<a href="{{menu_link}}">{{menu_text}}</a>' +
                            '<div class="menu_content"></div>' +
                        '</li>' +
                        '{{/menu_links}}' +
                    '</ul>',
'products_services':    '<div class="submenu">' +
                        '<ul class="top_list left">' +
                            '{{#top_list}}' +
                            '<li class="top_list_elem">' +
                                '<a href="{{top_list_link}}">{{top_list_text}}</a>' +
                                '<div class="extraInfo">' +
                                    '<div class="categories">' +
                                        '<ul>' +
                                            '{{#categories}}' +
                                            '<li class="category">' +
                                                '<div class="cat_name">{{category_name}}</div>' +
                                                '<ul class="subcategories">' +
                                                    '{{#subcategories}}' +
                                                    '<li class="sub_category"><a href="{{subcategory_link}}">{{subcategory_name}}</a></li>' +
                                                    '{{/subcategories}}' +
                                                '</ul>' +
                                            '</li>' +
                                            '{{/categories}}' +
                                        '</ul>' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                    '<div class="teasers">' +
                                        '{{#teasers}}' +
                                        '<div class="teaser">' +
                                            '<a href="{{teaser_link}}">' +
                                                '<img src="images/nav_teaser.jpg"/>' + 
                                            '</a>' +
                                            '<div class="caption">' +
                                                '<a href="{{teaser_link}}">{{teaser_caption}}</a>' +
                                            '</div>' +
                                        '</div>' +
                                        '{{/teasers}}' +
                                    '</div>' +
                                '</div>'+
                            '</li>' +
                            '{{/top_list}}' +
                        '</ul>' +
                        '{{#appointment}}' +
                            '<div class="right"><a href="#">Appointment</a></div>' +
                        '{{/appointment}}' +
                    '</div>',
'footer':           '<div id="footerWrapper" class="clearfix">' +
                        '<ul>' +
                        '{{#footer_list}}' +
                            '<li>' +
                                '<div class="title">{{footer_title}}' +
                                '</div>' +
                                '<ul>' +
                                '{{#footer_sub_list}}' +
                                    '<li>' +
                                        '<a href="{{footer_sub_link}}" class="{{footer_sub_link_class}}">' +
                                        '{{footer_sub_link_title}}' +
                                        '</a>' +
                                    '</li>' +
                                '{{/footer_sub_list}}' +
                                '</ul>' +
                            '</li>' +
                        '{{/footer_list}}' +
                        '</ul>' +
                    '</div>'
```

}

And this is the main js :

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
$.templates = function(page)
{
    var plugin = this;
    var mustache;
    plugin.init = function() {
        getHeader();
        getNav();
        getFooter();
    }

    var getHeader = function(){
        ...
    };

    var getNav = function(){
        var template = Templates.nav;
        var pages = ["products_services"];
       // setTimeout(function() {

            $.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "data/menu.json",
                dataType: "JSON",
                success: function(data) {
                    $('#menuWrapper').html(Mustache.render(template, data));

                    $.each(pages, function(key, val){
                        var template = Templates[val];
                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "data/"+val+".json",
                            dataType: "JSON",
                            success: function(data) {
                                var html = Mustache.render(template, data);
                                var menuContent = $('#'+val).find('.menu_content');
                                menuContent.html(html);
                                menuContent.find('.top_list_elem').bind('mouseenter', function(){
                                    var categories = $(this).find('.categories');
                                    var teasers = $(this).find('.teasers');
                                    var categoriesH = categories.outerHeight(true);
                                    var teasersH = teasers.outerHeight();
                                    var height;
                                    if((categories.width() + teasers.width()) > $(window).width())
                                        height = categoriesH + teasersH;
                                    else
                                        height =  Math.max(categoriesH, teasersH);
                                    menuContent.height(height + 50);
                                });
                                menuContent.bind('mouseleave', function(){
                                    $(this).height('');
                                });
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            })/*;},30)*/;
    };


    var getFooter = function(){
        ...
    };

    plugin.init();
}
$.fn.templates = function(page)
{
    return this.each(function()
    {
        if (undefined == $(this).data('templates'))
        {
            var plugin = new $.templates(page);
            $(this).data('templates', plugin);
        }
    });
}
var body = $('body');
var page = body.attr('id');
body.templates(page);

});
```

If it helps with anything.... : If I add the timeOut function that's commented out it works, but when I simulate a slow internet connection, the problem still exists..

The json files:

menu.json:

```
{
"menu_links": [
    {
        "menu_link": "#",
        "menu_text": "link1",
        "menu_id": "link1"
    },
    {
        "menu_link": "#",
        "menu_text": "link2",
        "menu_id": "link2"
    },
    {
        "menu_link": "#",
        "menu_text": "link3",
        "menu_id": "link3"
    },
    {
        "menu_link": "#",
        "menu_text": "link4",
        "menu_id": "link4"
    }

]
}
```

products_services.json is very long, so here is a snippet :

```
{
"top_list": [
    {
        "top_list_link": "#",
        "top_list_text": "Top List Text",
        "categories": [
            {
                "category_name": "Name",
                "subcategories": [
                    {
                        "subcategory_link": "#",
                        "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "subcategory_link": "#",
                        "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "subcategory_link": "#",
                        "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "subcategory_link": "#",
                        "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name 1"
                    },
                    {
                        "subcategory_link": "#",
                        "subcategory_name": "Subcategory name 1"
                         ...
            ...
```

I hope I provided enough information.
Thank you for the answers in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We loaded the data with javascript objects instead of json and it works...